# Elastic Search design for nested of nested data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am intending to use Elastic Search as primary datastore and my documents are like this nested of nested data. Events has 3 levels of nested data.

```
{
"Date": "2015-10-21",
"Hour": "7",
"Minute": "15-29",
"Domain": "abc.com",
"Processed_at": "10/23/2015 9:47 UTC"
"Events": [
  {
    "Name": "visit",
    "Count": "188",
    "Attributes_Aggregations": [
      {
        "Name": "price",
        "Value_Aggregations": [
          {
            "Value": "$125",
            "Count": "188",
            "Unique_Users": [
              {
                "ID": "CL_2135514566_1427476812_392007750_2004930118",
                "Count": "38"
              },
              {
                "ID": "CL_2135514566_1427476812_392007750_2004930119",
                "Count": "32"
              },
              ....
            ]
          },
          ....
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "color",
        "Value_Aggregations": [
          {
            "Value": "red",
            "Count": "188",
            "Unique_Users": [
              {
                "ID": "CL_2135514566_1427476812_392007750_2004930118",
                "Count": "38"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "Name": "order_created",
    "Count": "159",
    "Attributes_Aggregations": [
      {
        "Name": "price",
        "Value_Aggregations": [
          {
            "Value": "$125",
            "Count": "159",
            "Unique_Users": [
              {
                "ID": "CL_2135514566_1427476812_392007750_2004930122",
                "Count": "32"
              },
              ....
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
 ]
}
```

If i consider to use parent/child relationship structure but as per the [Elastic document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-performance.html) this level of parent/child query will become slow.

Is there any other idea to design the document to best fit in Elastic Search?

My desired queries will be using all the keys of the document to filter. range and count also to be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested queries if you define the structure at mapping as `nested`, as explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html). I'm not sure why nafas didn't mention this. Queries will be quite nasty to write though.

Comment: good point here, I don't remember why we didn't use this structure during our design, but I'm sure there was something that stopped us doing, honestly I don't remember

Comment: getting child documents from nested queries seems not possible. here is my another question on that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33763910/elastic-search-querying-filtering-nested-arrays/

Comment: Ahaa I didn't understand that was desired. I guess only option is to use nested fields for filtering, fetch the whole document and re-implement the filtering yourself to get the sub-structure you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Elastic Search is a great tool, however there is a major downfall in nested data, the problem is that ES flatten the array of objects, so if you query the nested info it returns them all.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

for example if you query for `Unique_Users.Count=38` it will return you

```
          {
            "ID": "CL_2135514566_1427476812_392007750_2004930118",
            "Count": "38"
          },
          {
            "ID": "CL_2135514566_1427476812_392007750_2004930119",
            "Count": "32"
          }
```

because this particular array (`Unique_Users`) has a field `Count` that matches `38`

Comment: yes, nested query will not work on this as you said. I am looking some other ideas like denormalise the data and using joins would work

Comment: @Shivaganesh we use same structure, once data is read we remove unnecessary stuff. this approach might not be ideal but works and usually fast if response is not big(100k+)